# Showing that $\mathrm{Var}(XY)=E(X)^2 \mathrm{Var}(Y)+E(Y)^2\mathrm{Var}(X)+\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)$

Tags: probability

I only know how to show that $$\mathrm{Var}(XY)=E(X)^2 \mathrm{Var}(Y)+E(Y)^2 \mathrm{Var}(X)+\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)$$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but how can I prove that this equation is still correct if $Y$ is mean independent of $X$ and the conditional variance of $Y$ given $X$ is constant?

Comment: What's the definition of being mean independent?

Comment: The conditional expectation of Y given x is the same for all x-values. It implies that Y is uncorrelated with X --> C(X,Y)=0       -->E(X^r Y)= E(X^r) E(Y)

Answer (score 2):

If both ${\rm E}[Y\mid X]$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y\mid X)$ are assumed to be constants, then also
$$
{\rm E}[Y^2\mid X]=\mathrm{Var}(Y\mid X)+{\rm E}[Y\mid X]^2,
$$
is constant. Constant random variables is, of course, equal to their mean, and hence
$$
{\rm E}[Y\mid X]={\rm E}[Y]\quad\text{and}\quad{\rm E}[Y^2\mid X]={\rm E}[Y^2].
$$
Now, use the rule that ${\rm E}[Z]={\rm E}[{\rm E}[Z\mid U]]$ with $U=X$ in the expression:
$$
\mathrm{Var}(XY)={\rm E}[X^2 Y^2]-{\rm E}[XY]^2.
$$